# Graph3D behavior does not seem to be following the given options. Is this a bug or am I not stating the options properly?

Tags: graphics3d

Something simple like RotationAction->"Clip" doesn't perform the intended change.

Example:

```
Graph3D[RandomGraph[{20, 30}],
        RotationAction -> "Clip", 
 PlotRegion -> {{0.25, 0.75}, {0.25, 0.75}}]
```

The user experience with Graph3D seems frustrating to me. The frequent zoom changes are jarring and they do not allow PlotRegion to display as intended. Alternatively, I am unable to specify whether to give some breathing room for the graph, so that it doesn't clip as it rotates.

Am I doing something wrong? is it just buggy?

IMO: An effective platform is created by aesthetic considerations, by cleaning up the loose ends, not by adding more and more pointless detail.

edit:

The PlotRegion specification was copy-pasted from an example in the option's documentation.

By breathing room, I mean padding or margins or range beyond the extent of the graph object.

[This is what I see](https://i.imgur.com/nkgdDFT.mp4) (using the same specifications as Syed). The graph rotation is very smooth but the zoom-level and frame-size keep changing. It would be unusable if, for example, a functional Graph3D object was the main element of a module.

Syed's example is smooth, though. David's example is a still life but I believe that it indeed works flawlessly. I am unsure about the cause for the differences in behavior.

(Running version 12.3.1.0; MacOS)

Updated title.

Comment: Works flawlessly for me.  (v. 11.3, MacOS). By the way, could you point to one or two of the "pointless details" you rue?

Comment: In spite of the unwarranted attitude and lack of specificity, when moving the `RandomGraph` the graph immediately jumps, then moves smoothly but when the mouse button is released, the `RandomGraph` jumps again (back towords the center?) even when `SphericalRegion -> True` is added.  (Windows 10, Mathematica 12.3.0.0)

Comment: What do you mean by 'flawlessly' @DavidG.Stork? When I run the example code (v12.3.1, MacOS), the plot appears very zoomed in. Upon rotation, it zooms out to the specified PlotRegion bounds and zooms back in when rotation stops, despite the RotationAction specifying otherwise. The documentation says that the default "Fit" option "will typically make the graphics appear to jump slightly when the mouse is released," which is occurring. As to your question, I was making a general statement about aesthetics/design, not detailing anything besides the main question.

Comment: See my "answer" below.

Comment: For clarification: `PlotRange->{{0.25, 0.75}, {0.25, 0.75}}` is what's 'causing' the bugginess.  `PlotRange->Automatic` has some idiosyncrasies, but I don't think they are what is being identified as an issue.  Feel free to edit the question with specifics so we can clean up this post.

Comment: @Adam, I have edited the answer to add another capture so as to compare PlotRange specifications side by side.

Comment: @Adam It's `PlotRegion` not `PlotRange`.

Comment: Please edit this post and add a title that summarizes your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why the rotation of Graph3D's output doesn't seem to be controllable with options such as `RotationAction` or `SphericalRegion` is that it contains

```
BaseStyle -> {Graphics3DBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}}}
```

You can see it like this:

```
SeedRandom[3456];
g = Graph3D@RandomGraph[{6, 8}]
Options@Show[g]
```

```
{BaseStyle -> {Graphics3DBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}}},   
 Boxed -> False, FormatType -> TraditionalForm, 
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", GrayLevel[0.7], 
    ImageScaled[{1, 1, 0}]}, {"Point", GrayLevel[0.9], 
    ImageScaled[{0, 0, 0}], {0, 0, 0.07}}}}
```

<del>I do not know how to disable this directly in `Graph3D`</del>, but you can disable it when converting a `Graph3D` to `Graphics3D`, using

```
Show[g, BaseStyle -> {}]
```

You can add other options to `Show` at the same time, such as `RotationAction -> "Clip"`.

---

EDIT: @ChipHurst gives the solution in a comment. Use the following:

```
Graph3D[..., BaseStyle -> {Graphics3DBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> False}}}]
```

It is *not* sufficient to use

```
Graph3D[..., BaseStyle -> {}]
```

Comment: `Graph3D[RandomGraph[{6, 8}], BaseStyle -> {Graphics3DBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> False}}}, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
 PlotRegion -> {{0.25, 0.75}, {0.25, 0.75}}]` seems to give the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much! That creates the intended behavior. And thanks for showing the Options@Show[ g ] way of gathering the options, as I would have assumed it to be the same as Options[ g ].

Comment: Very good Szabolcs and @ChipHurst!  I see that 'Options@Show[g]` for *Mathematica* 12.2 (Windows 10) does NOT have `BaseStyle` as an option.  So that option appears to have just been added to 12.3 (Windows 10).  Possibly the default for future versions of *Mathematica* might be better changed to have `"ShrinkWrap" -> False`.

Answer (score 4):

It works as David G. Stork mentioned.

[image]

**Second edit:**

For the OP command exactly, here is a shot. I used 'Automatic' to save on the white space. I am on version 12.2 on Win7.

[image]

**Third edit:**

JimB is using commands not specified by the OP. And here is a third capture for comparison.

[image]

Comment: Identical to my screen.  Indeed:  flawless.  Whether or not someone accepts the OP's claim (which have NO evidence) and reject my claim.  So 100% of the evidence shown on this page proves that the system works flawlessly.  Over and out.

Comment: What operating system and version of *Mathematica*?

Comment: Also, those are not the commands that the OP used.

Comment: Ooops!  I did leave in ":>" rather than "->" as I tried that, too, but it makes no difference.  (I'll modify my answer.)  However, when I try it with *Mathematica* 12.2, it works just like you show it.  So maybe it's a 12.3 issue.

Comment: Let's wait for a while, so other 12.3 users on Win10 can share their experience.

Answer (score 2):

This post just shows the undesired behavior as captured:  The scale starts off in the `PlotRegion` requested but with attempts at rotation results in an immediate rescaling of the graph.  Then the rotation is smooth.  But once the mouse button is lifted, the graph jumps.  (Windows 10, *Mathematica* 12.3.0.0).

[image: Evidence of jumpiness]

Comment: Use ScreenToGif for smaller capture sizes.

Comment: @Syed. Thank you. I’ll try that.

Comment: @Syed.  That works great!  Much more compact than what I was using.

Comment: I have this exact behaviour (windows 10 mm12.3) . Szabolcs and Chip Hurst's suggestion does work!

Answer (score -2):

The graph rotates flawlessly, without change of scale, position, etc.:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do 4 static frames show that "the graph rotates flawlessly" ?

Comment: Because I'm telling you that.  Geez...  Do you actually think it is jumping around, but the static frames all just happen to be perfect?  Really?  You're turn:  Prove to us that the image is showing the flaws that are claimed.  Why should we believe you?

Comment: You're right:  I'll post an animated gif as evidence.  (*Mathematica* is now in the process of downloading FFmpeg so I can convert a jumpy mp4 to an animated gif).  You're wrong:  you have shown no evidence.